# webservices registration error

Tags: ios, gracenote

After I return results from "GNSearchResponse" I get this error:

```
reportSearchResults = "RecognizeFromMicOperation: [5000] webservices registration error: GCSP: Hello error: [130] Please contact Gracenote ODP 04616 [Name: Steve McIntyre] [App: fb music] support.\n[Gracenote Error 130/74]";
```

Not sure what this error is. My app is registered. There's nothing that indicates I'm not registered. My app has worked up until a week ago.

Comment: It may be that your Client ID has expired. You may need to speak to a Gracenote representative to extend it or if possible try creating a new one.

Answer (score 1):

I had to renew my contract for another year. Once I renewed, everything worked without changing any code.